# Why is it that a matrix that is not invertible cant be expressed as a product of elementary matricies

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I understand there is a property of invertible matrices that states: "a square matrix is invertible iff it can be written as a product of elementary matrices"

However i need help proving this and justifying it

Comment: Because all elementary matrices are invertible?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2899761/why-is-a-matrix-invertible-if-it-can-be-written-as-the-product-of-elementary-mat

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is a matrix invertible if it can be written as the product of elementary matrices?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2899761/why-is-a-matrix-invertible-if-it-can-be-written-as-the-product-of-elementary-mat)